# Updates for Ubuntu on phones

Tags: updates, ubuntu-touch, phone, smartphone, bq

I've got some questions concerning updates for Ubuntu on phones.

- What is the release cycle of Ubuntu on phones? Is it the same
  as for the desktop version?
- Who is responsible for providing updated images for the different phones?
  The manufacturers or the Ubuntu community?

And to be more specific:

- I'm curious about the BQ Aquaris E4.5. How long will it be supported
  with updates and how fast will they be delivered?
- Will the update process for Ubuntu on phones be the same mess as the one on Android (where you don't if and when you'll get an update for your phone)?

Comment: I'm not an expert of this topic but I was an attendant in a [conference](http://www.meetup.com/Barcelona-Free-Software/events/221967219/) 3 days ago and if I understood well I can answer few questions. The release cycle of Ubuntu is the same as in desktops. Ubuntu community is responsible for providing updated images. The other questions I don't know that's why I just add a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phone does track the major 6 month releases, but in addition there are updates planned basically every 4 to 6 weeks. These updates provide both bug fixes and new features. The Ubuntu community makes the updates and the manufacturers are involved in the validation process.

The length of time a particular phone receives updates will likely vary based on the device

We plan to avoid fragmenting by making updates available for all supported devices at or around the same time. This assumes the proper agreement by the manufacturer or carrier.

Comment: Via the mailing list https://lists.launchpad.net/ubuntu-phone/ it is possible to keep watch on (upcoming) updates.